# Error when importing M2Crypto in Python on Windows x64

Tags: python, import, openssl, runtime-error, m2crypto

I'm trying to use the M2Crypto library on Windows 64 bit. I'm using a 64 bit version of Python and I've compiled M2Crypto from source, linking against Openssl 1.0.2d. This compilation was successful and I've installed the package by running `python setup.py install`.

When I run `Python` from command line and I type `import M2Crypto`, it works. Next, I'm trying to use the library by creating an Elliptic Curve key:

```
from M2Crypto import EC
kp = EC.gen_params(EC.NID_sect233k1)
kp.gen_key()
kp.save_key("test.key", None)
```

This gives the following error:

```
OPENSSL_Uplink(00007ABCAFE839000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink
```

I'm not really sure what to do with this error. I think the issue has to do with Openssl. Some sources on internet are writing that I should recompile Python but I'm not sure how to do that. I am wondering whether there is a more easy way to fix this error since I don't like to recompile my Python distribution.

This issue is only occurring on Windows. I have no problem with installing M2Crypto on OS X or Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not reproduce your issue with my own installation of Python and M2Crypto. However, I have seen the `no OPENSSL_Applink` happen on Windows when `openssl/applink.c` was not included and compiled into the application and when subsequently a `BIO` was used to write to a file or to `stdin` or `stdout`.

Therefore, you could try using a memory BIO and then reading from that memory BIO and writing the contents to a file in Python itself, like this:

```
>>> from M2Crypto import EC
>>> kp = EC.gen_params(EC.NID_sect233k1)
>>> kp.gen_key()
>>> from M2Crypto import BIO
>>> membuf = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
>>> kp.save_key_bio(membuf, None)
1
>>> with open('test2.key', 'w') as f:
...     f.write(membuf.read())
...
```

This is not a real fix, just a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tested it out and it seems to work! I will go this way instead.